# Conflict with id in related data search yii2

Tags: gridview, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

Ok here is my problem

i am displaying 2 related columns in a gridview
both from same foreign table
i am displaying first name and lastname as fullname
and email as another column
all those 3 data are from same table

```
 'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn'],
        [

            'attribute' => 'event_id',
            'label' => 'Event Title',
            'value' => 'event.title'
        ],
        [
            'attribute' => 'user_id',
            'label' => 'Name',
            'value' => 'users.fullname',
        ],
        [
            'attribute' => 'user_id',
            'label' => 'Email',
            'value' => 'users.email',
        ],
```

As you can see i have to give attribute as `user_id` if i want to make it searchable
here is my `search` model

```
$query->joinWith(['event', 'users']);
$query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'event.title', $this->event_id]);
    $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'user.firstname', $this->user_id]);
    $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'user.email', $this->user_id]);
```

Now the problem is search on email works fine i mean when i enter any data in searchbox of email columns it renders the `user_id` fine but it automatically creates query like `where email=blah blah AND firstname=blah blah`
In fact i havent entered any data in `fullname` column search box

When i enter any data in `fullname` column search it doesnt evet find the `user_id` of that table

how should i resolve this conflict???
Ohh and my database structure is something like this
this gridview is of `checkin` table in which i am displaying all the users who checked in to particular event
so there are 2 more tables `event` and `users`

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `event` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `organiser_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `interest_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `location` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `is_active` bit(1) NOT NULL,

) 

 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `firstname` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dob` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `username` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `area_intrest` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `checkin` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `event_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_type` enum('competitor','fan') NOT NULL,
)
```

Here is my Search function code

```
class CheckinSearch extends Checkin
```

{

```
public $fullName;
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['id', 'created_by', 'updated_by'], 'integer'],
        [['user_type', 'user_id', 'event_id', 'created_date', 'updated_date','fullName'], 'safe'],
    ];
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function scenarios()
{
    // bypass scenarios() implementation in the parent class
    return Model::scenarios();
}

/**
 * Creates data provider instance with search query applied
 *
 * @param array $params
 *
 * @return ActiveDataProvider
 */
public function search($params)
{

    if(!isset($_GET['id'])){
        $id='';
    }
    else{
        $id=$_GET['id'];
    }

    $query = Checkin::find()->where(['event_id'=> $id]);

    $query->joinWith(['event', 'users']);


    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

    $this->load($params);

    if (!$this->validate()) {
        // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
        // $query->where('0=1');
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    $query->andFilterWhere([
        'id' => $this->id,
        'created_date' => $this->created_date,
        'created_by' => $this->created_by,
        'updated_date' => $this->updated_date,
        'updated_by' => $this->updated_by,
    ]);

    $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'event.title', $this->event_id]);
    $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'user.firstname', $this->fullName]);
    $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'user.lastname', $this->fullName]);
    $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'user.email', $this->user_id]);
    $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'user_type', $this->user_type]);

    return $dataProvider;
    }
}
```

If i add both firstname and lastname filter it generates query like this

```
   SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `checkin` LEFT JOIN `event` ON `checkin`.`event_id` = `event`.`id` 
LEFT JOIN `user` ON `checkin`.`user_id` = `user`.`id` WHERE 
((`event_id`='11') AND (`user`.`firstname` LIKE '%text%')) AND 
(`user`.`lastname` LIKE '%text%')
```

I want to generate query like this using the AND or OR filter

```
SELECT * FROM `checkin` LEFT JOIN `event` ON `checkin`.`event_id` = `event`.`id` 
LEFT JOIN `user` ON `checkin`.`user_id` = `user`.`id` WHERE 
((`event_id`='11') AND (`user`.`firstname` LIKE '%text%')) OR 
((`event_id`='11') AND (`user`.`lastname` LIKE '%text%'))
```

thank you

Comment: You must change the  of one of the above `user_id`attribute to other name.

Comment: @InsaneSkull yeah you are right but that `email` comes from the same table as `firstname` and `lastname` so what should i use instead of `user_id`?

Comment: you can use `join` to get data from more tables and it is easy to create `searchModel` from it.

Comment: @InsaneSkull you mean like this? `$query->joinWith(['event', 'users']);` because i have 2 relationships so i am joining with 2 tables on same page. Or you are talking about something else?

Comment: gridview displaying data for both email and fullname?

Comment: `$query->joinWith(['event', "users"]);` and using `
    $query->andFilterWhere(['like', "user.firstname", $this->user_id]);` is this ok?

Comment: @InsaneSkull  thats the first thing i tried.. its in the question as well.. The problem is same it conflicts with `email` as `fullname` and `email` comes from same table.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://webtips.krajee.com/filter-sort-summary-data-gridview-yii-2-0/

Comment: @InsaneSkull hey thank you for that guide now the problem was i was suppose to declare that rulename as public on top liek `public $fullName;` whichi was missing. Searching is working but i have another problem now it searches only the `firstname` if i add another `Andfilterwhere` rule for `lastname` it `AND` the result so it gives me all data from the table not for particular `event_id`

Comment: cause you don't have `full name` so you have to combine both fields then compare with your post data.

Comment: @InsaneSkull yeah i got that part but i want to make that search work for both firstname or lastname so i have added search logic and query i want let me know if you can help me with that.. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create one more variable for full_name in your model, add that variable to safe search & use that variable for searching & also while displaying full name.

Suppose your new variable is "full_name"

Then in your search function add following line

```
$query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'user.firstname', $this->full_name]);
```

In view

```
[
    'attribute' => 'full_name',
    'label' => 'Name',
    'value' => 'users.fullname',
],
```

Comment: i have `getFullName()` function in `Users` model and in the current model's rules section i included `fullname` nad also included ` $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'fullname', $this->fullname]);` and my view file `'attribute' => 'fullname','value' => 'users.fullname',` but i am getting error that `CheckinSearch::fullname` getting unknow property

Comment: this problem seems to come from my search model rule section.. I did included `['fullname'], 'safe'` in `CheckinSearch` but still getting unknown property error

Comment: replace $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'fullname', $this->fullname]); with 
$query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'user.firstname', $this->full_name]);
and $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'user.lastname', $this->full_name]);
in your search function

Comment: tried that too. Same error unknown property `CheckinSearch:fullname` but i have defined in rule section of `Checkin` model. `Checkin` and `Users` model do have relationship defined as well

Comment: have you defined variable "fullname" in your model Checkin class

Comment: yes i did.. but still `$this->fullName` is not getting resolved

Comment: add following rule in your Checkin model
['fullname', 'string', 'length' => [500]]

Comment: yes i did that too.. So now `Users` model has `getFullName()` function. `Checkin` Model has that safe rule `fullName`and `['fullname', 'string', 'length' => [500]] ` and `CheckinSearch` has that same `fullName` rule and `view` is something like this `'attribute' => 'fullName','value' => 'users.fullname'`. Still same error. i tried replacing with the query you gave me as well

Comment: add criteria->with = 'user' in your search function and compare fullname with user.firstname & user.lastname separately

Comment: i dont know how `criteria` seems to fit my sitution but its been deprecated in yii2 version anyway

Comment: check out this link http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/653/displaying-sorting-and-filtering-model-relations-on-a-gridview/

Comment: thank you @RohitGaikwad i have already gone through that article. Dont know how it helps me in my sitution

Comment: add this "['fullname', 'string', 'max' => 500]," in your CheckinSearch's rules and try.

Comment: Nope not working.. See the query i posted in question and help me in that manner if you can... i can get the value entered in the search box i just need to search it in right manner

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for your help guys
but i came accross a question on stackoverflow and solved it
here is what i did

```
$query->andFilterWhere(['or',
        ['like','user.firstname',$this->fullName],
        ['like','user.lastname',$this->fullName]]);
```

this query will look in both `firstname` or `lastname`
seems to solve my problem now